# swfobject undefined ie when embedding youtube videos

Tags: internet-explorer, youtube, swfobject

I have an issue that I cant seem to solve
I have this site [http//:makeandsee.com/shadow.html](http://makeandsee.com/shadow.html)

It pulls in all the youtube videos from a single youtube user and displays them, which all works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE it throws up an error saying the swfobject isnt defined which makes no sense because all other browsers have no issues any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting access to the swfobject in Javascript? And *not* doing something like this?

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if (window.document[movieName]){
        return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1){
        if (document.embeds &amp;&amp; document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else{
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
    }
}
```

Comment: im using `function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
  swfobject.embedSWF(
      playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + 
      (autoplay?1:0)+'&version=2.2', 'player', '550', '350', '9.0.0', false, 
      false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
}`